# Programa não respondendo PYQT5, quando eu necessito que ele fique parado por alguns segundos (WIFI,UART,ESP32)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Eu estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, meu programa envia quando o objeto,  modemlist que é um QComboBox está na opção WIFI eu envio uma solicitação para o esp me mostrar as redes disponiveis e isso demora um pouco, então eu tenho que por um time.sleep(x) ou qualquer forma de segurar o programa para que ele espere a resposta do esp32, o problema está no seguinte, ele está conectado numa seguinte função

```
self.modemlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(
                        lambda: self.trata_dropmenus(1))

def trata_dropmenus(self, dropmenu):
    print("a")
    #Inicio do tratamento das opções do Modem#
    if (dropmenu == 1):
       text = "Modem: "
       text = text + self.modemlist.currentText()
       if(text == "Modem: Wifi"):
          self.wifiwindow.recebe_serial(self.srch, self.cbport, self.textBrowser_1, self.textBrowser_2, self.textBrowser_3)
          self.wifiwindow.pedelista()
          self.wifiwindow.show()
```

A função pedelista() irá mandar o comando para o esp via uart e ficar esperando a resposta e é nisso que ele trava, mas ele mostra a tela não esta respodendo mas depois que o esp32 responde ele eu apenas clico em aguardar e ele volta normalmente

```
 self.ser = serial.Serial(
                self.writePort.currentText(), 115200, timeout=3)
 self.ser.write(text.encode())
 packet_not_complete = 1
 tm = time.time()
 while(packet_not_complete!=0):
                try:
                    while(self.ser.in_waiting<=0 and time.time()-tm< 12):
                        print("Is waiting")
                        time.sleep(1)
                    packet_not_complete = 0
                except:
                    pass
self.line = self.ser.readline()
self.line = self.line.decode()
print("Resposta recebida :")
print(self.line)
```

EU já tentei criar uma thread para que ele fique esperando em segundo plano mas não houve diferença porque ele ainda dava o erro de não esta respondendo, a solução que eu tive mas apenas para testar foi criar um botão para pedir a lista de wifi, o que funcionou

```
self.atualizawifi.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.pedelista())
```

Desde já agradeço estou a disposição de mandar imagens do erro e etc, se alguem pode me ajudar a entender porque eu não posso fazer issso com o combobox, e se tem alguma forma eu agradeço

Obs: A função pedelista, está na classe wifi que eu coloquei  wifiwindow = wifi ()
ela está funcionando perfeitamente, esse botão atualizawifi tambem está dentro dessa classe

Comment: Duas sugestões: (i) tira o try/except para ver se tem alguma exceção sendo gerada. Uma vez que o except está fazendo apenas `pass`, (ii) Use o debug `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` e veja o que está acontecendo.

Comment: OI Paulo tudo bem , eu fiz seus dois testes mas não resolveram meu problema, eu fiz um outro teste para havaliar como funciona as ligações dos QcombBox, eu fiz uma lista de menu simples e pois ligado a uma função que apenas iria contar tempo, e da o mesmo erro, então por algum motivo listas de menus não podem demorar muito nas funções, eu resolvi trocar por um botao para atualizar o wifi mesmo kkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que é comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. No seu caso, como vc mesmo encontrou a solução, basta usar o campo de respostas abaixo (o textarea "Sua Resposta"), e depois [marque-a como aceita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido.